# How to create matrix in Stata

Tags: matrix, random, stata, probability-distribution

I want to make a sample of two variables, according to a specific probability distribution.
I thought of making a matrix that expresses the probability distribution but my code results in `p is not defined`.

```
p = matrix(c(0.04,0.1,0,0.06,0.05,0.3,0,0.05,0.14,0.1,0.06,0.1), nrow=3, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 
sample_100 = rDiscrete(n=50000,pf=p)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks to me as if you are using R or R-like syntax in Stata. That's not going to work.

Comment: I see... What is a STATA way then?

Comment: If you have access to Stata start with `help matrix`.

Comment: You got a good answer, but a better question would show some attempt at code in the language you're asking about. Otherwise Stack Overflow would be swamped with questions of the form: What is the code for task X in language Y?

Comment: @NickCox’s point is a very good one!

Comment: Thank you everyone! Well it still says "'p' found where '(' expected"...
I want to create a random sample of two variables, and with a matrix of probability distribution is already given. I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to use Stata, you are giving us an error message, but no code. Please edit your question to show Stata code, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to create the matrix in your `matrix()` command:

```
matrix input p = (0.04,0.1,0,0.06 \ 0.05,0.3,0,0.05 \ 0.14,0.1,0.06,0.1)
```

This answers the question in the title of your post. If you provide more information about your question, you may be able to elicit a more complete answer.

As I mentioned: `help matrix` will give you the documentation, which will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the code and see help at the same time